How do we capitalize Bitcoin (or BitCoin, or bitcoin)?
In this question (where the topic includes the word "BitCoin") eMansipater writes the following in regards to capitalization:

The capitalisation thing is my own arbitrary convention to
  differentiate the technology (BitCoin), the open-source client
  (Bitcoin) and the unit of currency (bitcoins)

I believe that this is way too complicated and that it's better to stick to one way of writing it. Especially the "BitCoin" version seem unnecessary. I would like us to be able to quickly edit topics that use "incorrect" capitalization so that the site looks clean, but then we have to decide on something.
Please write you suggestion in an answer and we'll let the votes decide.

+1. I know it might seem pedantic to some, but we're promoting a product here, so just as the top execs at Intel used to insist that my spec docs say "600 MHz Intel Pentium III Processor" instead of "p3 600" we need to be a bit pedantic sometimes to ensure that our "brand" keeps a professional look.

One suggestion:

Use Bitcoin (with a capital "B") when talking about the concept/technology.
Use bitcoins (no capitalization) when talking about the unit of currency (4 dollars - 4 bitcoins).
Never use BitCoin or BitCoins


yeah BitCoin has always looked fugly

This is quite sensible. Other currencies don't get capitalized, but other project names do.

Where would "BTC" fit in to this, if at all?

@billpg BTC while not officially accepted it fits the role of currency code. Similar to USD or EUR Maybe someday BTC will be the iso standard abrevation for bitcoins http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php

BTC is the unit of currency, pronounced "bitcoins". "4 bitcoins" is ambiguous since it could mean either 4 BTC or 4 TBC.

Yes, this is consistent with the FAQ on the talk page for Bitcoin on Wikipedia.

Nowdays I am using only bitcoin lowercase, even for the technology because I think it's a common name now.
